# A Python try/except function to rule them all (with different inputs) is possibile?

Tags: python, function, error-handling, try-catch, except

I'm trying to define in Python a try/except function that can handle various other function.
The idea is quite this one:

```
def func1(x,y):
    z = x+y
    return z
    
def error_check(func1):
    try: stuff = func1()
    except: 
        print('Error')     
    return stuff
    
error_check(func1('1',2))
```

In this case, with those inputs, the error_check function doesn't even work.
The aim is that I can use error_check with another func2 with a diverse number of inputs. For examples:

```
def func2(w,x,y):
    z = w+x+y
    return z
```

Is that possible?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem with this whole idea is that catching an error doesn't mean you fixed the error.  Just try your function with a `func1` that raises an exception and you'll see the problem:

```
>>> def error_check(func1):
...     try:
...         stuff = func1()
...     except:
...         print('Error')
...     return stuff
...
>>> def oops():
...     raise ValueError
...     print("Computing the answer...")
...     return 42
...
>>> error_check(oops)
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in error_check
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'stuff' referenced before assignment
```

Note that we don't see `Computing the answer...` in the output, and our function does not return 42!  **There is nothing we can do in `error_check` that will change this.**

The problem is that if `func1` raises an exception, *it does not return anything*.  Hence there is no `stuff` to return.  You can't force a function to "work" by just ignoring the exception it raises; if a function raises an exception, it means *it could not do the thing it was supposed to do*.

Maybe you're okay with this and want your `error_check` to return `None` instead of whatever `func1` was supposed to return.  If so, you could do:

```
def error_check(func1):
    try:
        return func1()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error")
```

This will implicitly return `None` if there's an exception.  It won't raise another exception, but `func1` is still not going to do the thing that it was supposed to do:

```
>>> error_check(oops)
Error
>>>
```

Note that if we needed that `42` value for something else in our program, *that* thing is now probably going to raise an error, and if you catch that error, the thing after *it* will raise an error, and so on, and so on.  Ultimately, you don't do yourself any favors by just catching errors and ignoring them.

All that said, if you want to be able to pass other arguments to `func1`, use `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
def error_check(func1, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return func1(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Now you can do:

```
error_check(func1, '1', 2)
```

and `func1` will be called within `error_check` with `*args` of `('1', 2)`.

Comment: If you return a tuple in both cases `return (func1(*args, **kwargs), None)` or `return (None, Exception)` you kind of  end up with `go` like error handling :-)

Comment: indeed, although why anyone would ever want that is beyond me :P

Comment: Once you did, it would allow people to lament having to check for errors all the time and wish they could use try blocks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that in the last line there, you are actually calling `func1` and then calling `error_check` on the result. Try something like this instead, where the `lambda` delays evaluation until the `try` block like we want:

```
def func1(x,y):
    z = x+y
    return z
    
def error_check(func1):
    try:
        stuff = func1()
        return stuff
    except: 
        print('Error')     
        return None
    
error_check(lambda: func1('1',2))
```

You also have an error in that `stuff` is undefined if the `try` block failed, so I took the liberty of fixing that.